# Can I configure a visual difference view with the notifications provided by TFS?

Tags: tfs, diff

I have TFS sending me alerts whenever someone on my team checks in code. (I had to create notification rules for every project, but that's just a sidebar complaint in this question.)

These alerts provided some information on who checked in the files when, and what files have changed, with urls to view details in a browser. The thing that baffles me is that I can't just click on the source file and see a visual diff of the changes. There's no link that will auto-launch a diff in Visual Studio (using a custom protocol) from there either.

Is there a way to configure TFS to provide a visual diff of the changes to the file that was checked in via this notification UI?

Comment: I don't have an answer, but I do share your frustration!

Comment: Thanks for sharing the pain, Marcie :) I'm going to look at the TFS power toys next to see if they get me any closer to this functionality.

Answer (score 1):

[TFSSpam](http://tfsspam.codeplex.com/) might be a solution - it sends notification emails when changesets come in with a graphical diff in the body of the email.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. IIUC, that looks like something I'd install on the TFS server, which may be an issue. It's good to know the solution exists but it sounds like TFS won't provide what I'm looking for without a custom add-on.